# i want to stream the audio file from my dropbox folder in the android app also is there any need of using dropbox's core API?

Tags: audio-streaming, dropbox-api

i want to stream the audio file from my dropbox folder in the android app also is there any need of using dropbox's core API? I have tried and sometimes it worked for other sites url's like gannna.com but not always...